# WhatsApp automation: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

I am trying to run a python script to automate WhatsApp messages but when I run the script, I get this error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x011EDF13+2219795]
        Ordinal0 [0x01182841+1779777]
        Ordinal0 [0x0109423D+803389]
        Ordinal0 [0x010B591A+940314]
        Ordinal0 [0x010B181E+923678]
        Ordinal0 [0x010AF179+913785]
        Ordinal0 [0x010E36B9+1128121]
        Ordinal0 [0x010E331A+1127194]
        Ordinal0 [0x010DE616+1107478]
        Ordinal0 [0x010B7F89+950153]
        Ordinal0 [0x010B8F56+954198]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x014E2CB2+3040210]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x014D2BB4+2974420]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x01286A0A+565546]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x01285680+560544]
        Ordinal0 [0x01189A5C+1808988]
        Ordinal0 [0x0118E3A8+1827752]
        Ordinal0 [0x0118E495+1827989]
        Ordinal0 [0x011980A4+1867940]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x762E7BA9+25]
        RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x775DBB3B+107]
        RtlClearBits [0x775DBABF+191]
```

I found this script on GitHub that uses Selenium. I am pasting the code link below:

[GitHub Link for the code](https://github.com/anirudhbagri/whatsapp-bulk-messenger/blob/primary/automator.py)

What could be the solution for this? The code doesn't even open a chrome window and puts the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating Selenium & Chrome. It worked fine for me using Selenium 4.5.0 & Chrome 106.0.5249.62.